# Formatting Dates while using the UCanAccess JDBC driver

Tags: java, datetime, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

When using the UCanAccess driver in Java, I am finding it very difficult to output dates into specific formats. Currently, I am using the PreparedStatement.setDate() method which requires the date to be in the format [yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss]. The resulting output, when a user opens the file up, is also in this format.

EDIT* - I am not using the setDate() method with the formatted date, this method only accepts Java Date objects which have no formatting. What I meant to write was that I am using the setString() method when dealing with a formatted date, but UCanAccess requires this date String to be in the format [yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss]. I am really just trying to figure out how to either feed it a different format or change the format after I have called setString().

So far this has been fine, but now I have a need to deliver the file with dates in various formats such as [MM-dd]. I can do this already by making the resulting Access field type a Memo or Text, but the problem becomes when I need the date to be in that format and still have the resulting Access field type be a Date/Time.

I noticed on the [UCanAccess front page](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html), it mentions supporting Access date format but I am not finding any examples anywhere after several Google searches. Anyone know how to format dates using this driver while maintaining the correct Date/Time type?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `PreparedStatement.setDate()` expects a `java.sql.Date` parameter which does not have a format (and it's not used for doing "output" either)

Comment: You are most correct @a_horse_with_no_name, I am using the setDate() method when using Java Dates (just a long, no formatting), and then using the setString() method when setting a date with formatting. This requires the format [yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss]. I was trying to make it so that I can feed it any format or change the format programmatically after calling setString()

Comment: Don't use `setString()` for dates. use `setDate()`. The formatting of dates should be handled when *displaying* (=reading) the data in your frontend, not when saving it.

Comment: Well that is the issue here is that I am given formatted dates in the String format and I need to open the formatting up a bit to allow other styles. In addition, I would like to deliver a "finished" Access file where the dates are formatted in the manner desired instead of having to open the file up and make the changes manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you retrieve a Date/Time field value via UCanAccess you get a `java.sql.Timestamp` object. It contains the Date/Time value, but it does not have a format *per se*.

If you want to *represent* that Date/Time value in a particular way you just need to format it to your liking. Probably the simplest way to do that is with `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`. For example:

```java
try (ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT DateJoined FROM Members WHERE MemberID=1")) {
    rs.next();
    System.out.printf(
            "         \"raw\" value (via .toString()): %s%n", 
            rs.getTimestamp(1).toString());
    SimpleDateFormat mmddFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd");
    System.out.printf(
            "formatted value (via SimpleDateFormat): %s%n", 
            mmddFormat.format(rs.getTimestamp(1)));
}
```

gives us

```
         "raw" value (via .toString()): 2014-01-23 00:00:00.0
formatted value (via SimpleDateFormat): 01-23
```

(Note that when the UCanAccess page talks about the "Access date format" it is referring to Date/Time literals enclosed in hash marks like this: `#11/22/2003 10:42:58 PM#`. However, you should almost never need to include date literals in your queries because you should be using a `PreparedStatement` with appropriate `.setTimestamp()` parameters.)

**Addendum**

Similarly, when inserting Date/Time values into the Access database: The formatting of the Date/Time value in Java makes no difference to the way the Date/Time value is stored in Access (provided that it is interpreted correctly), and the way it is displayed in Access is a function of the format settings *in Access*. For example, if we run the following Java code

```java
try (Statement s = conn.createStatement()) {
    s.executeUpdate(
            "INSERT INTO tblDates " +
            "(ID, mmddyyyy) " +
            "VALUES " +
            "('literal', #12/25/2014#)"
            );
}

SimpleDateFormat mmddyyyyFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Timestamp mmddyyyyXmas = 
        new Timestamp(mmddyyyyFormat.parse("12/25/2014").getTime());

SimpleDateFormat ddmmyyyyFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Timestamp ddmmyyyyXmas = 
        new Timestamp(ddmmyyyyFormat.parse("25/12/2014").getTime());

SimpleDateFormat yyyymmddFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
Timestamp yyyymmddXmas = 
        new Timestamp(yyyymmddFormat.parse("2014/12/25").getTime());

try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
        "INSERT INTO tblDates " +
        "(ID, mmddyyyy, ddmmyyyy, yyyymmdd) " +
        "VALUES " +
        "('parameters', ?, ?, ?)"
        )) {
    ps.setTimestamp(1, mmddyyyyXmas);
    ps.setTimestamp(2, ddmmyyyyXmas);
    ps.setTimestamp(3, yyyymmddXmas);
    ps.executeUpdate();
}
```

and then open the Access database with Windows set to use the default formats for "English (United States)" we see

[image: en_us.png]

If we change the format settings in Windows to "English (United Kingdom)" then we see

[image: en_gb.png]

If we want to use a particular format for one or more fields we need to use a specific Format setting in Access, e.g., with something like this

[image: DesignView.png]

we see

[image: DatasheetView.png]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm actually not trying to query data out of an Access database, but rather trying to insert data into one. I need the date to be shown to the user in a specific format when opening the file itself.

Comment: @ksmark By "opening the file itself" you mean opening it in Access? If so, then Access will default to using the `General` Date/Time format which "... is a combination of the Short Date and Long Time settings" as defined in the Windows control panel (Regional settings) (ref: [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/format-property-date-time-data-type-HA001232739.aspx)). If you want to see a particular format in Access then you need to specify it **in Access**, e.g., in the `.Format` property of the Table field or of a specific Form/Report control.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the very detailed reply here. That sucks, so there is no way to programmatically set the Access .Format property? This has to be done post-Java-production of the file?

Comment: @ksmark I don't believe there's a way for Jackcess (and hence UCanAccess) to specify the .Format for a field when creating a new table. However, you could use Access to create a database file with the formatting you desire (for Tables, Forms, Reports), leave the tables empty, and then use UCanAccess to push the data into a copy of that "skeleton" file instead of creating a new empty .accdb/.mdb file from scratch.

Comment: Hmm there may be some light to that solution. In either event thanks for all the help with this one!